# How to bind list of string in kendo dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

Hello I am using Kendo for ASP.NET MVC.

I have list of string containing data

```
[0]="str1"
[1]="str2"... and so on
```

Now I want to bind this list of string into kendo dropdownlist.

I have bind dropdownlist by list of class with name and id but with only one data in list of string, I don't know how to bind that!

I have done that like below:

```
 @(
                 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name("ddlstrings")
                            .DataTextField("stringname")
                            .DataValueField("stringname")
                            //.Events(x => x.Select("sourceclick"))
                            .SelectedIndex(0)
                            .DataSource(source =>
                                {
                                    source.Read(read =>
                                    {
                                        read.Action("getData", "String");
                                    });
                                })
                )
```

But I got undefined.

I am returning the data like this:

```
public JsonResult getData()
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> stringlist = object.getstrlist();
                return Json(stringlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this!

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: what is the return type of your `getData` Action ?

Comment: By *list of string*  you mean a javascript array or a c# List ?

Comment: return type is json and return data is from list of string from c# and I updated the question please see it so you can have better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you have provided is right actually. The Action must return  `List<SelectListItem>` as the output. [See this Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/index) and in the code see the `BindTo` property.

You can just update your code to below.

```
        public JsonResult getData()
        {
            try
            {
                var stringlist = object.getstrlist().select( x=> new SelectListItem
                             {
                              Value = x,
                              Text = x
                             }).ToList();


                return Json(stringlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

I have just modified your code to not have a for loop.

Comment: Ohhh yes no need to use for loop. Thanks it reduced my code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know is it good or not but got the solution with some manual work:

```
var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var element in stringlist)
                {
                    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = element.ToString(),
                        Text = element.ToString()
                    });
                }

return Json(selectList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and at view side:

```
@(
                 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name("ddlstrings")
                            .DataTextField("Text")
                            .DataValueField("Value")
                            //.Events(x => x.Select("sourceclick"))
                            .SelectedIndex(0)
                            .DataSource(source =>
                                {
                                    source.Read(read =>
                                    {
                                        read.Action("getData", "String");
                                    });
                                })
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ValuePrimitive:

```
                    Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .Name("ddlstrings")
                        .ValuePrimitive(true)
                        .SelectedIndex(0)
                        .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("getData", "String");
                                });
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your `getData()` return? You need to return an enumerable of object that have a property called `stringname` or what ever property name you specify in the DataText/DataValue fileds.
Something like this:
`return Json(youStringArray.Select(x=>new{stringname = x}))`

Comment: No it still set undefined value. I have updated the question please see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using TestSolution.Utility;
 ...

public JsonResult getData()
{
   try
   {
     var stringlist = object.getstrlist();
     return Json(stringlist.ToIdNameList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}

=============================

using TestSolution.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestSolution.Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Kendo Drop Down List Extention
    /// </summary>
    public static class KendoDropDownListExtention
    {
        public static List<IdName> ToIdNameList(this string[] stringList)
        {
            return stringList.Select(sl => new IdName() { Name = sl, Value = sl }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```